# Hive table created successfully but data from S3 bucket is not imported

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

Created a table and want to move the data from a S3 bucket.
Table is created, but data is not imported from S3.
What could be the problem? Please help me out, thanks in advance.

**Following is the series of commands and the respective output:**

```
hive> CREATE TABLE contraceptive_usage_data( wife_age int, wife_edu int, husb_edu int,no_of_children_born int, wife_religion int,
    > wife_now_working int, husb_occu int, stand_living int, media_exposure int, contraceptive_method_used int) ROW FORMAT 
    > DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' location 's3://emr.learnings/contraceptive_data/contraceptive_usage_data_indonesia_1988';
OK
Time taken: 16.452 seconds
hive> select * from contraceptive_usage_data limit 10;
OK
Time taken: 1.966 seconds
hive>
```

**Sample data in the S3 bucket**

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
28, Private, 338409, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Prof-specialty, Wife, Black, Female, 0, 0, 40, Cuba, <=50K
37, Private, 284582, Masters, 14, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Wife, White, Female, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
49, Private, 160187, 9th, 5, Married-spouse-absent, Other-service, Not-in-family, Black, Female, 0, 0, 16, Jamaica, <=50K
52, Self-emp-not-inc, 209642, HS-grad, 9, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 45, United-States, >50K
```

Comment: Were you able to find the answer? I'm hitting the exact same problem and I'm using the EXTERNAL keyword as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the keyword EXTERNAL,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE contraceptive_usage_data( wife_age int, wife_edu int, husb_edu int,no_of_children_born int, wife_religion int,
wife_now_working int, husb_occu int, stand_living int, media_exposure int, contraceptive_method_used int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION 's3://emr.learnings/contraceptive_data/contraceptive_usage_data_indonesia_1988';
```

I think without the EXTERNAL keyword, Hive will try to create a new empty table at the location instead of loading the existing data there.

Comment: You mean table in created in S3 location? I tried the above but still I dont find data getting imported once the table is created

Comment: Yeah then I'm stumped. I assume you've tried moving that file into an S3 location that you have write access to?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the space after every , in the values .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).